# Can't use URL module on Node.js, cannot call method 'parse' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I'm trying to get parameters from a URL, for example:

```
http://localhost:8888/?name=test
```

To get `name` parameter I saw some samples where they use the `url` module like this:

```
var url = require('url');

var urlParts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = urlParts.query;
```

So, first I ran this command `npm install url`, also the dependency is on the `package.json` file, but I always get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'parse' of undefined
at C:\Users\Administrator\git\test\app.js:28:7
```

Anyone has faced this problem before?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(url);`?

Comment: I found the problem (see comment below), thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 12):

I found the problem, I had the code like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var urlParts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = urlParts.query;
}).listen(appport);
```

And the `url` object was not accessible inside the `createServer` function (not sure why), so I just replace this line:

```
var urlParts = url.parse(request.url, true);
```

with this:

```
var url_urlParts = require('url').parse(request.url, true);
```

and now is working fine.

Comment: Did you perhaps have a second `var url` inside the `createServer` callback somewhere?

Comment: My only concern with your solution is that `require` is one of few synchronous methods in node (it was a nightmare when it wasn't apparently) so you're making a blocking call in handler.  This may or may not be an issue, because it's also pretty smart and caches requested files.  Just might want to verify that.

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't know about that, I'm going to take a closer look at this

Answer (score 2):

This one bit me too - my problem was that `url.parse` was conflicting with a local var `url`. I solved it like this:

```
import { parse as urlparse } from 'url'
var url = 'https://localhost:80'
var parsed_url = urlparse(url)
```

Thanks [@loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

function parse(urlStr: string, parseQueryString: true, slashesDenoteHost?: boolean): UrlWithParsedQuery (+3 overloads)
@deprecated — since v11.0.0 - Use the WHATWG URL API.

'(urlStr: string, parseQueryString: true, slashesDenoteHost?: boolean): UrlWithParsedQuery' is deprecated.ts(6385) url.d.ts(51, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Comment: DEP0116: Legacy URL API#
History
Version Changes
v15.13.0 
Deprecation revoked. Status changed to "Legacy".

v11.0.0 
Documentation-only deprecation.

Type: Deprecation revoked

The Legacy URL API is deprecated. This includes url.format(), url.parse(), url.resolve(), and the legacy urlObject. Please use the WHATWG URL API instead.