# TypeError: Cannot call method 'parse' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I want to parse my req.url using url.parse() method.But it's showing

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'parse' of undefined
```

code:

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

the req.url value:

```
 /auth/google/callback?state=example+return+string&code=4/FTbL4FcZ5-Lj7cHdb9gdz8GG1zMVdxWw8IzANsowFAA.ciQe3G7mL4YYcp7tdiljKKbTnUsmmAI&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&prompt=consent&session_state=d61f28145e5edbae1580aebbb36aea97a7f07cde..3baf
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't overwriting your `url` variable?

Comment: I'm overwriting it..1st time it was '/' and after that it is  /auth/google/callback?state=example+return+string&code=4/FTbL4FcZ5-Lj7cHdb9gdz8GG1zMVdxWw8IzANsowFAA.ciQe3G7mL4YYcp7tdiljKKbTnUsmmAI&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&prompt=consent&session_state=d61f28145e5edbae1580aebbb36aea97a7f07cde..3baf

Comment: Could you provide more context? Running your provided 3 lines of code works as expected. Perhaps @BenFortune is onto the problem.. Try `console.log(url)` right before you're about to use `url.parse` to confirm `url` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Hi Marco,I solved the problem from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414169/cant-use-url-module-on-node-js-cannot-call-method-parse-of-undefined